# How to start pulseaudio for all users at startup?

Tags: pulseaudio, startup, root, users

I am trying to use `pocketsphinx` but it gives me :

> ad_oss.c(115): Failed to open audio device(/dev/dsp): No such file or
>   directory FATAL: "

And I know I must start pulseaudio, but when I try :
`pulseaudio --start` it gives me:

> N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at
>   {89a9b504dcf44323b304020cdcab105b}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native,
>   which appears to be local. Probing deeper.

How can I change the settings to autostart pulseaudio for all users at the startup? (even root user)